# Calculating delta numbers from an excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel

I want to calculate delta numbers from an excel spreadsheet. Right now I can calculate delta numbers only for one row. I want to automate the process of calculating delta numbers. Here's my code:

```
import os
os.chdir("/Users/user/Desktop")

import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('lotto.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

def delta():
    a = sheet['A2'].value
    b = sheet['B2'].value - sheet['A2'].value
    c = sheet['C2'].value - sheet['B2'].value
    d = sheet['D2'].value - sheet['C2'].value
    e = sheet['E2'].value - sheet['D2'].value
    f = sheet['F2'].value - sheet['E2'].value
    return [a, b, c, d, e, f]

delt = delta()
delt.sort()

if delt[-1] < 16:
    print("The delta numbers are: " + str(delt))
else:
    print("These are not delta numbers.")
```

Here is the excel spreadsheet:

http://ge.tt/3lZEnrw2

Comment: Why have you missed first row (`A1, B1`... )?

Comment: The numbers in the first row are not delta numbers.

Comment: you can pass row number as an argument to your delta function and change the `sheet['A2'].value` by `sheet['A%d'%row_num].value` likewise.

Comment: Can you give me the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all rows:

```
import openpyxl

def delta(i):
    a = sheet[f'A{i}'].value
    b = sheet[f'B{i}'].value - sheet[f'A{i}'].value
    c = sheet[f'C{i}'].value - sheet[f'B{i}'].value
    d = sheet[f'D{i}'].value - sheet[f'C{i}'].value
    e = sheet[f'E{i}'].value - sheet[f'D{i}'].value
    f = sheet[f'F{i}'].value - sheet[f'E{i}'].value
    return sorted([a, b, c, d, e, f])

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('lotto.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
for row in range(1, sheet.max_row+1, 1):
    d = delta(row)
    if d[-1] < 16:
        print(f'{d[0]}-{d[1]}-{d[2]}-{d[3]}-{d[4]}-{d[5]}')
    else:
        print('--------------------')
```

Output:

```
--------------------
1-2-3-7-9-10
3-4-6-7-9-15
```

etc.

Comment: If they are delta numbers they should be printed like this: 1-2-3-7-9-10. If they are not delta numbers they should be printed like this: --------------------. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The better way to manipulate the value in the excel sheet is using panda data frame. Open the sheet using panda data frame and simply subtract from one column to another column.

Here is the code -

```
import pandas as pd

# Assign spreadsheet filename to `file`
file = "/Users/user/Desktop/lotto.xlsx"

# Load spreadsheet
#If you get an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'" then install the 'xlrd' package by pip install xlrd
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

# Print the sheet names
print(xl.sheet_names)

# Load a sheet into a DataFrame by name: df
df = xl.parse('Sheet1',header=None)
#Example for delta calculation of cloumn 0 from column 1
diff=df[1]-df[0]
```